# Modified copies of line sed / awk

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I'm trying to insert modified copies of lines after the original lines.

Here's my file:

```
random
N:John Doe
random
N:Jane Roe
random
random
N:Name Sirname
random
```

Here's what my file need needs to look like:

```
random
N:John Doe
FN:John Doe
random
N:Jane Roe
FN:Jane Roe
random
random
N:Name Sirname
FN:Name Sirname
random
```

Any ideas for this one? Can't seem to find the right sed/awk combination...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -n ' p; s/^N:/FN:/p' original.txt
```

This produces:

```
random
N:John Doe
FN:John Doe
random
N:Jane Roe
FN:Jane Roe
random
random
N:Name Sirname
FN:Name Sirname
random
```

It works as follows.  We invoke `sed -n` which means that, by default, it won't print any lines.  Then, we give it two commands.  The first, `p`, is to print the existing line *unmodified*.  The second, `s/^N:/FN:/p`, tells it to try to substitute `FN:` for any leading `N:` and, if that substitute succeeds (meaning that the line actually did start with `N:`), then *also* print the modified version.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with the following:

```
sed -e 's/^\(N:.*\)$/\1\nF\1/g' yourfile.txt
```

This uses a regular expression to find a file that starts with the character sequence "N:".  When it finds it, it replaces that line with `\1\nF\1` (the original line, plus a newline, plus a capital 'F', plus the original line again).

This all assumes that the "random" lines don't happen to start with "N:".

Answer (score 2):

### Use Ampersand to Insert a Copy of Match

The ampersand will insert a copy of the full match from the left-hand side into the right-hand side of a sed expression. So, using a simple substitution to place a newline and a leading F between copies of your match is all that's needed. For example:

```
$ sed 's/^N:.*/&\nF&/' /tmp/corpus.txt 
random
N:John Doe
FN:John Doe
random
N:Jane Roe
FN:Jane Roe
random
random
N:Name Sirname
FN:Name Sirname
random
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
awk '/N:/{print $0"\nF"$0;next}1' file
```

```
$ cat file
random
N:John Doe
random
N:Jane Roe
random
random
N:Name Sirname
random
```

```
$ awk '/N:/{print $0"\nF"$0;next}1' file
random
N:John Doe
FN:John Doe
random
N:Jane Roe
FN:Jane Roe
random
random
N:Name Sirname
FN:Name Sirname
random
```